# How to find a character which can’t be stored in a MySQL “utf8” column in Java

Tags: java, mysql, unicode

I use MySQL 5.7 and I have a table which has a column which uses the “utf8” character set. Unfortunately it is not utf8mb4, therefore I always get an error when my app tries to insert a character which is out of the range of “utf8” (E.g. emojis).

Unfortunately I can’t change the character set to “utf8mb4” soon, so I wonder if it’s possible to detect those characters which make the error happen before it gets inserted into the table and let our customers know that they can’t use them.

I read somewhere that anything outside the range of U+0000 to U+FFFF makes the error happen. My app is implemented in Java 8. So, my question is: how can I write code which can find such problematic characters from a String instance? Does [the following code](https://github.com/nuzayats/mysqlutf8mb3validation/blob/master/src/main/java/utf8/Utf8Mb3Validator.java) do the thing I want?

```java
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Utf8Mb3Validator {

    /**
     * finds characters which can’t be stored in a MySQL “utf8” column out of a given String.
     *
     * @param input a String which you want to check
     * @return a Set which contains strings that can't be inserted into MySQL "utf8" columns
     */
    Set<String> findProblematicStrings(String input) {
        // References:
        // https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb3.html
        // https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/supplementary-142654.html?printOnly=1
        // https://stackoverflow.com/q/56800767/3591946
        return input
                .codePoints() // get Unicode code points
                .filter(codePoint -> Character.charCount(codePoint) > 1) // search for non-BMP characters
                .mapToObj(codePoint -> new String(Character.toChars(codePoint))) // convert code points into Strings
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

I also posted this question to the MySQL forum: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,675862,675862#msg-675862

Comment: Have you seen the article [Supplementary Characters in the Java Platform](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/supplementary-142654.html?printOnly=1) ?

Comment: Thanks, I have just read it. Iterating a return value of String#codePoints() with if(Character.charCount(codePoint) == 1) seems to be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed MySQL's `utf8` was correct at the time as UTF-8 multi-byte sequences had at most only 3 bytes. But Unicode got more symbols, and UTF-8 grew too. And **only** `utf8mb4` can do.

However upto 3 bytes all is okay:

```
return input
      .codePoints()
      .filter(codePoint -> codePoint >= 256) // Optional heuristic optimisation
      .mapToObj(codePoint -> new String(Character.toChars(codePoint)))
      .filter(cpString -> cpString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length > 3)
      .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Or simply all [codepoints above U+FFFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8):

```
return input
      .codePoints()
      .filter(codePoint -> codePoint >= 0x1_0000)
      .mapToObj(codePoint -> new String(Character.toChars(codePoint)))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I honestly admit, I would need to research whether `Character.charCount(codePoint)` could be used too, as it checks on surrogate pairs in UTF-16, and not the number of bytes in UTF-8.

Useful might be `Character.getName(codePoint)` to substitute the codepoint with (if the fields have a sufficient long size).

Comment: According to OpenJDK's source code, it seems that `Character.charCount(codePoint)` does the same thing as your latter solution http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Character.java#l4818

Comment: @KoheiNozaki nice implementation then. With a kind of knotted logic.

Comment: This one might be even cleaner https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,675862,675956#msg-675956

Answer (score 0):

If there is a method in Java to produce the hexadecimal representation of the `UTF-8`-encoded string, then search for an `F0` byte in the string.

If there is a method in Java to produce the 16-bit representations of the `UTF-16`-encoded string, then search for any 16-bit that contains a `D8xx-DFFF` value.

(Point me at some such methods and maybe I can elaborate.)